# Is there a way to Grep multiple HTML pages on a domain without downloading the files?

Tags: grep, wget, curl, pipe

I essentially want to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> multiple sites in a browser.

I have a range of URLs on a domain `https://exampleblog.com/posts/{1-50}`

I want to grep all of the pages under `/posts/` at once. They are each identified with an ordered int from 1 to 50.

Is there a way to do this without downloading with `wget`? I want to grep the information I get back from `curl`.

I feel like there is an eloquent pipeline or one liner that would allow me to do this from the terminal without downloading (although it may be slow).

Comment: This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1750445/167207) is correct: Even if the files are not actually download, you need to retrieve the content (aka: download it) to grep it locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note that even curl will download the page, it'll just don't write it to a file, but to stdout instead.**

### Method 1

`curl` supports getting URLs sequentially:

```
curl 'https://exampleblog.com/posts/[1-50]' | grep <searchterm>
```

### Method 2

You could just do a for loop:

```
for i in {1..50}
do
    curl https://exampleblog.com/posts/"$i" | grep <searchterm>
done
```

### Method 3

If you do not have a sequential number in the URL, you can use `wget` recursively instead. It will parse the downloaded page for URLs and follow the found links. The `--no-parent` option ensures that it only downloads pages in the same subdirectory and deeper in the hierarchy, in this case `questions`.

**Note that if there is no link that matches the criteria in the downloaded page, `wget` will not load it, even if other pages on that website might reference it.**

```
wget --recursive --no-parent https://superuser.com/questions/1750443 -O ./test.out
grep <searchterm> test.out
rm test.out
```

Comment: Or only `curl 'https://exampleblog.com/posts/[1-50]' | grep <searchterm>`.

Comment: I like the solution @Cyrus commented. What if the sub routes were dates or text strings instead of ordered integers?

Comment: @Cyrus I did not know that curl was able to sequentially request URLs, thanks for the addition! I've edited that into my answer, if you want to write your own answer I can remove it of course.

Comment: @dcannistraro `wget` supports recursive operation, where it follows all links it can find on that page. You can specify that it only follows links in that same directory with `--no-parent`. You will need to write it to a file, but you can simply delete it afterwards. Example: `wget --recursive --no-parent https://superuser.com/questions/1750443 -O ./test.out`

Comment: @dcannistraro: In this case, you need a loop that does the job. But something like `[a-g:2]` would also be possible to loop `a`,`c`,`e` and `g`. See `man curl` and search for `counter` for more details.